# GWT get started servlet crash problem

Tags: gwt, servlets

followin this tutorial

http://code.google.com/intl/et-EE/webtoolkit/gettingstarted.html

im in section : **Run locally in development mode**

eclipse gives me the url to run it locally

http://127.0.0.1:8888/Gtw_test.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997

i go to there with chrome and also firefox, then it like crashes/freezes and after 1-2 minutes it finally loads up..

in eclipse console i get these messages for both browsers:

```
[WARN] No file found for: /favicon.ico
[WARN] No file found for: /favicon.ico
[WARN] No file found for: /favicon.ico
```

problem is the freezing and the warnings.

btw when i tried URL : http://127.0.0.1:8888/ . it loads instantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run your application in development mode, code is being compiled and generated on the fly - this is why it takes so much time and application seems to freeze and generally work slower. Only the code which is request is compiled and generated, so you can test some of the features without the need of compiling the whole project.

For small application, you can compile your app and run normally, but for bigger projects it's better to use development mode. It loads longer and somewhat is slower, but it saves you a couple of minutes of compiling whole project (Eg. my project was compiling about 15 minutes with all locales and permutations).

Comment: but when i change a line in my code, lets say i change the name of the button, and save file when server is running. when i refresh my browser, does it compile it all over again? cause i tried it , but it didnt take 1-2 minutes when i refreshed, it took like few seconds

Comment: It depends what You change and how it affects whole application. If it affects only a part of it, it will recompile only files affected by that change. It also depends on additional modules and frameworks used.